# Completeness Theorem for a finite domain

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I take the Completeness Theorem to be saying the following:

> Any consistent, countable set of sentences has a model whose domain only contains natural numbers.

But something feels off when I apply this to a domain which is finite.  Suppose my domain is $D=\{d_1,\ldots, d_m\}$ and I have a model $\mathcal{M}$. Then $\mathcal{M}\models \textrm{'there are exactly m objects'}$ or more formally,

$$\mathcal{M} \models \forall y \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_m (x_1\neq x_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge x_{m-1}\neq x_m \wedge (y=x_1 \vee y=x_2\vee \ldots \vee y=x_m))$$

But surely $\mathcal{M}$ also satisfies the sentence which says "It is **not** the case there are $m+1$ objects" and "It is **not** the case there are $m+2$ objects" and so on.  So I have a countable set of sentences which are in fact consistent; therefore, it seems by the Completeness Theorem that there is a model $\mathcal{N}$ whose domain contains only natural numbers $N$.  But if this is the case, then in particular it has to still satisfy the sentence "there are exactly m objects" but wait $\mathcal{N}$ definitely does NOT satisfy this.  Where's my mistake?

Comment: The theorem doesn't say the model contains *all* natural numbers.

Comment: AH!   Awesome.  That makes sense.  So a model of paper rock scissors (for example) would (by the Completeness Theorem) be something like "1 < 2" and "2<3" and "3<1" (this would correspond to "Rock beats scissors" and "Scissors beat paper" and "Paper beats rock".  Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: That sentence doesn't say the model is finite. In any model: $\forall y\exists x(y=x)$ is true. You need to write it as $\exists x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m\forall y(\dots).$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that Max's comment addressed my concern.  However, I don't see how $\mathcal{M} \models \forall y \exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_m (x_1\neq x_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge x_{m-1}\neq x_m \wedge (y=x_1 \vee y=x_2\vee \ldots \vee y=x_m))$ doesn't actually say "there are m many objects".  How else would you say it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews .... yup I see that too now!  Thanks.  I need to correct this with something like "There exists m many objects and for all y, y is one of these x's".  I got my quantifiers backward!  Thank you very much Thomas

Comment: $\exists x\exists z  \wedge (x\neq z) \wedge  \forall y[ (y=x)\vee (y=z)]$ says there are exactly two objects.

Comment: Right, if you want "at most $m$ objects" then you can remove the $x_i\neq x_j$ part.

Answer (score 3):

The completeness theorem says that there must be a model that is countable or finite.

The statement

> ...has a model whose domain only contains natural numbers.

does **not** say

> .. has a model whose domain is the entire set of natural numbers.

It says "only contains natural numbers." This means that the domain is a subset of the natural numbers. This includes finite subsets.